# Added marker is not visible - Mapbox 6.7.0

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-android

While trying to add marker to mapbox using symbol layer, the marker was not visible.
Tried to add marker as shown below,

```
mapView.getMapAsync(m -> {
        isMapReady = true;
        mapboxMap = m;
        mapboxMap.addOnMapClickListener(MapViewFragment.this);

 addMarkerToSymbolLayer(45);
 updateCameraPosition(location); });

private void updateCameraPosition(Location location){

  if (mapboxMap != null) {
        LatLng latLong = new LatLng();
        if (location != null) {
            latLong.setLatitude(location.getLatitude());
            latLong.setLongitude(location.getLongitude());
        }
        final CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(latLong)
                .build();
        mapboxMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
        mapView.postDelayed(() -> mapboxMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition), AppConstants.MAP_CAMERA_ANIMATE_DURATION_MS_5000), 100);

private void addMarkerToSymbolLayer(float headDirection) {

    GeoJsonSource geoJsonSource = new GeoJsonSource("geojson-source",
    Feature.fromGeometry(Point.fromLngLat(77.6387, 12.9610)));
    mapboxMap.addSource(geoJsonSource);

    Bitmap compassNeedleSymbolLayerIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
            getResources(), R.drawable.compass_needle);

    mapboxMap.addImage("compass-needle-image-id", compassNeedleSymbolLayerIcon);


    SymbolLayer aircraftLayer = new SymbolLayer("aircraft-layer", "geojson-source")
            .withProperties(
                    PropertyFactory.iconImage("compass-needle-image-id"),
                    PropertyFactory.iconRotate(headDirection),
                    PropertyFactory.iconIgnorePlacement(true),
                    PropertyFactory.iconAllowOverlap(true)
            );
    mapboxMap.addLayer(aircraftLayer);

}
```

If addMarkerToSymbolLayer() is called after moving camera then the marker is visibile. Why is that adding marker dependent on camera position? I have to move camera many times to meet my requirement. How to handle this?

Also in the Deprecated MarkerView and MarkerViewOptions I didnt have any issues while adding marker.

I noticed that if given a delay of 100ms while calling the function addMarkerToSymbolLayer(45), the marker is visible and things work fine !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The onMapReady() is called even before all the styles have been loaded. It is necessary that all styles be loaded before adding a symbol layer. Add the following listener and call for adding marker inside it.

```
mapView.addOnDidFinishLoadingStyleListener(new MapView.OnDidFinishLoadingStyleListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDidFinishLoadingStyle() {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for making life easier :)